# How do we approximate the pressure in the Boussinesq equations of hydrodynamics?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, inequalities, navier-stokes

How do we approximate the pressure or the gradient of it in the Boussinesq equations of hydrodynamics ?
Is the pressure limited or can it be any amount?

Comment: Please be more concrete. I don't understand anything!

Answer (score 2):

I presume you wish to know how to obtain the pressure field in the [Boussinesq approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boussinesq_approximation_(buoyancy)) to the Navier-Stokes equations. In that approximation the pressure field $p(x,y,z,t)$ and the density field $\rho(x,y,z,t)$ are decomposed into a base $\bar{p}(z)$ and $\bar{\rho}(z)$ that are purely hydrostatic in a gravitational field,
$$\frac{d\bar{p}}{dz}=-\bar{\rho}g,$$
plus small perturbations $\delta p(x,y,z,t)$ and $\delta\rho(x,y,z,t)$ which may be linearized. This gives the Boussinesq equation for the velocity field $\vec{v}$,
$$\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial t}+(\vec{v}\cdot\nabla)\vec{v}-\eta\nabla^2\vec{v}=-\frac{1}{\bar{\rho}}\nabla\delta p-\frac{g\hat{z}}{\bar{\rho}}\delta\rho.$$

So to answer the OP: the pressure in the Boussinesq approximation is not limited, its gradient is just the mass density times the gravitational acceleration; it can be arbitrarily large.